# Force refresh image in update panel

Tags: asp.net, image, updatepanel

I have a button and an image in update panel. How do I  force the image refresh by clicking on the button?

**update**

```
    <b>Enter the code</b>
     <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
          <uc:TextBox ID="txtCaptcha" runat="server" />
          <asp:Button ID="btnRefreshCaptcha" runat="server" Text="Refresh the code" CausesValidation="false" onclick="btnRefreshCaptcha_Click" />
          </ContentTemplate>
          <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnRefreshCaptcha" EventName="Click" />
          </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: You should accept more answers people provide you.

Comment: Why aren't you doing this via a client side script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add random value parameter to the end of your image url and change that on each update

kind of ImageUrl = baseUrl + "?" + new Random().Next()

Comment: Lol, what the heck? It's 3:30 AM, am I dreaming or is this actually working? ... yeah, definitely time to give coding a rest.  And thank you!  It doesn't make sense but that's maybe because I am seeing sheep jump over the moon.

Comment: This works. DateTime.Now can be used instead of a random number for extra utility.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
Sub btnRefresh_Click() Handles btnRefresh.Click

    Me.Image.ImageUrl = "path to your image file"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

i used the above code but it shows the script problem in dropdown list what i gave it in master page and call them as a class files in every pages.After using the above code in my coding and i refresh the captcha it shows the overload of dropdownlist in my page and refreshment of captcha works only once after tis problem occurs i cant to refresh the captcha image in my page.